# Does $C\cap A = C\cap B$ implies that $A = B$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, examples-counterexamples

a) If $C\cap A = C\cap B$, can you conclude $A = B$? If you can, then prove it. Otherwise, give a counterexample and then describe an extra condition which will allow you to conclude $A = B$.

(b) Repeat part (a) for $C\cup A = C\cup B$.

(**My attempt for part a**):

Let $A$ be the set $\{x,y,z\}$. By the definition of intersection, for $C\cap A$, all common elements between $C$ and $A$ exist, thus $\{x, y,z\}$ must exist within $C$. And for $C\cap B$, all common elements between $C$ and $B$ exist, thus $\{x,y,z\}$ must exist within $B$. And since $C\cap A = C \cap B$, we can conclude that $A = B$.

(**My attempt for part b**):

Let $A$ be the set $\{x,y,z\}$ elements. By the definition of union, for $C\cup A$, then all elements between $C$ and $A$ must exist, thus $\{x,y,z\}$ must exist within $C$. And for $C \cup B$, then all common elements between $C$ and $B$ exist, thus $\{x,y,z\}$ must exist within $B$. And since $C\cup A = C\cup B$, we can conclude that $A$ and $B$ are equal subsets of $C$, and thus $A = B$

Was my approach to both parts wrong? I would really appreciate the feedback. Thank you.

Comment: "if **C ∩ A**, then..." This doesn't make sense. "$C\cap A$" is not an assertion, it is a set.

Comment: I have worded that incorrectly, my apologies.

Comment: What do you mean by "all common elements between $C$ and $A$"? While $C\cap A\subseteq A$, why $\{x,y,z\}$ must exist within $C$?

Comment: "Let A be the set {x,y,z}. " But what if $A$ is *different* set? You can't show something for *one* set and then assume it is true for *all* sets.  "all common elements between C and A exist" Not nescessarily.  Maybe $A\cap C$ is empty. That's still a set. " all common elements between C and A exist, thus {x,y,z} must exist within C" But you don't know *which* elements of $A$ are also withing $C$. It could be some and not others, it could be none of them.  You have no reason to assume it is *all* of them and if you think about it you should realize it is an absurd claim.

Comment: Suppose $A= \{x,y,z, purple, orange, blue\}$ and $B = \{x,y,z, monkey, dishwasher, kleenex\}$. and $C= \{x,y,z, candy, maggots, George Washington\}$ then $A\cap C = \{x,y,z\}= B\cap C$ but $A \ne B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both claims are false.

(a) Consider $C = \{1\}$ where $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{1,2\}$. Then $C\cap A = C\cap B$, but $A\neq B$.

(b) Consider $C = \{1,2\}$ where $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{2\}$. Then $C\cup A = C\cup B$, but $A\neq B$.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is false, take $C=\emptyset$, $A=\mathbb{N}$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}$, then $C \cap A = \emptyset = C \cap B$ but $A \neq B$.

Your second statement is also false: take $A=\mathbb{Q}$, $B=\mathbb{Z}$ and $C=\mathbb{R}$, then $C \cup A = \mathbb{R} = C \cup B$ but $A \neq B$.

Your mistake is that you are *choosing* sets $A ,B$ and $C$, they must be arbitrary sets (in general).

Comment: I think the problem is with understanding definitions/concepts rather than with the structure of the argument.